# cakephp bindmodel limit problem db2

Tags: cakephp, db2

i encountered an error while binding a model with a hasMany relation. while binding, i also set the limit to '5'. unfortunately when the query is run, the limit turns to 0 (e.g. FETCH FIRST 0 rows). anyone had similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to put your query exactly after your bindmodel statement